# Yarrow and weak cryptographic keys on macOS

Tags: keys, entropy

Given that macOS uses Yarrow as a PRNG, and Yarrow is only capable of 160 bit outputs (/dev/random on macOS is actually Yarrow) are keys generated on macOS weaker than Linux?

Even BSD has switched to Fortuna.

Is this is big gaping hole in Modern macOS security?

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yarrow_algorithm

EDIT:

I have looked through the source and it seems as if they switched to a DRBG NIST generator?

https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-4903.221.2/osfmk/corecrypto/ccdbrg/src/ccdrbg_nisthmac.c.auto.html

There are very few references to Yarrow in the 10.14 XNU code compared with older versions of the Kernel, but 10.14 still contains this string in key.c :

```
/* Our PRNG is based on Yarrow and doesn't need to be seeded */
That said if you looked at older XNU Yarrow is littered everywhere.
```

**Source code for XNU:**

[Lots of Yarrow references in XNU 2782 - macOS 10.11](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-2782.40.9/)

[Very few Yarrow references in XNU 4903 - macOS 10.14](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-4903.221.2/)

So, are Apple still using Yarrow?

---

---

### Update: Apple are [using Fortuna](https://support.apple.com/en-ie/guide/security/seca0c73a75b/web).

---

---

Comment: Does  it block like Linux when entropy runs out/is insufficient?

Comment: Nope! Neither dev/random or urandom block.

Comment: Only FreeBSD switched to Fortuna with SHA-256. OpenBSD and NetBSD use ChaCha20 as the core primitive.

Comment: @PaulUszak Once sufficient entropy has been collected, it never "runs out".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Whilst the estimation of input entropy is regarded as conservative (as is Linux's), not blocking means that [information theoretic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information-theoretic_security) secure output cannot be achieved.  So any key or keys generated in an (output length) > (input entropy) situation can theoretically be inverted/predicted. It is not mathematically impossible, only computationally difficult (at present). Tomorrow or the day after it may become possible.

   We can't predict the future, but one consequence of macOS is that it cannot be used to generate a one time pad.  Therefore macOS keys can be viewed as being less secure than /dev/random Linux keys in this (rare) use case. That means it's one small crack, rather than a gaping hole, and exists irrespective of the 160 bit key space.
2. Above excepted, given side channel attacks and side of side channel attacks, I suggest that there is no holistic security difference between a 256 bit key and a 160 bit key (the problems with SHA1/3DES aside).  Mathematically $2^{256} > 2^{160}$. But given all current and future side channels, I can't see a practical real world difference when trying to preserve a secret.

---

Holistic security: security in the whole given all aspects of a political, economic, social and technological analysis ([PEST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PEST_analysis)). E.g. What's the difference between key sizes when Australia has now [outlawed](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-australia-46463029) unbreakable encryption? E.g. Why brute force a key when a key logger/camera is less costly to install?  E.g. Or hack the phone rather than the  $n$ bit app?

Comment: What exactly is the definition of `Holistic security` doing at the bottom of this answer? It does not appear to be related...

Comment: Interesting and thank you. Two quick follow ups. Surely a one time pad is possible on macOS assuming entropy is present up to 160bits of OTP should be possible? Secondly does this mean it’s effectively impossible to generate > 160bits of cryptographically secure key on macOS? I regularly use it for 256bit keys using common crypto. Not sure what to think.  EDIT: seems they switched their prng https://opensource.apple.com/source/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto-60118.220.1/lib/CommonRandom.c.auto.html

Comment: @Woodstock No, that wouldn't be possible because the 160 bits are not independent.

Comment: Paul, there is no way there will be a 160-bit SHA-1 preimage "tomorrow". Computationally difficult does not mean "well, we think it's pretty hard", it means "this will not happen before the sun burns out".

Comment: @EllaRose It's mentioned in point 2 - _"...there is no holistic security difference..."_. I've used it before as well in other answers/comments.  It's my response to the worrying drift on this site towards only 256 bit keys becoming acceptable, which in my mind creates a very false sense of security when considering the whole security environment (PEST).

Comment: @Woodstock 1) No, I don't think that you could get 160 bits of information theoretically secure material with any confidence.  Without the entropy estimator blocking the output, 1000's of bits of random bytes will have been pulled from Yarrow for the OS/network to operate.  That will have stretched accumulated seed entropy as $YARROW:\{0, 1\}^{n} \to \{0, 1\}^{m}$ with $m >> n$, especially by the 3DES component.  Consequently the algorithm can be inverted to recover the seed and variables allowing future prediction.  It's currently hard, but not mathematically impossible, so no true OTP.

Comment: @PaulUszak would you be comfortable using macOS to generate a key you were using for something important?

Comment: @Woodstock 2) The definition of cryptographic is the hard bit.  Yes, for _this_ site, the macOS keys are cryptographically secure, just like Linux's.  That's because 160 bits is very very good.  You don't get the true 256 bits though.  All you got was two 160 keys related by a counter passing through 3DES, concatenated and truncated back down to 256 bits.  I'm pretty sure that forest's answer is numerically more accurate at 2 x 112 bits, but I was focusing on OTPs that creates a very clear distinction between the two OS's.

Comment: @Woodstock I'd be very happy at 128 bits. Look at the [effort required to brute force 128 bits](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6141/amount-of-simple-operations-that-is-safely-out-of-reach-for-all-humanity/6149#6149).  Holistically, it's total useless.  No one's going to try.  I'll just locate you, break into your house and steal your PC.  Or take the original papers lying on your desk, and make it look like a drug burglary.  Look at all other breaches.  There's a million side/side of side channels that mean the brute force effort threshold is a lot lower than 256 bits.

Comment: Thanks @PaulUszak- appreciate the response. I completely appreciate the strength of 128 bit security is still mind boggling and nearly beyond human comprehension. That said, let's be fair, I think it's quite surprising, many people including Apple talk about and champion 256bit security. Including Apple's own Disk Utility. Why even include the option to use 256bit AES on macOS? It's pointless. As is 256bit ECC, blows my mind. I cannot understand how a modern OS from a company like Apple thinks this is OK.

Comment: @Woodstock You're absolutely right and I can't properly explain this nor reconcile all of the various arguments. It's a PESTy problem. But we are in danger of setting off the conversations-not-allowed-in-comments droid. Simply consider the security level of a Mac phone or laptop carried through a US port of entry. What use any bits at all when they order you to decrypt in order to clone the drive? And now social media passwords for visa applicants? The Australian experiment? FaceID by judicial force? All pretty much off topic for this site...

Comment: Thanks @PaulUszak they can take my keys from my dead neurons. :)

Comment: @Woodstock Careful. Uszaks feed on positive attention. They are an invasive species that thrive in an environment where it takes five down votes to cancel out the rep gained from one up vote. To the untrained eye they mimic the native fauna very well. It's in noone's interest to leave scraps out for the Uszak. They will keep coming back for more food and never develop the skills to earn compliments in the wild. -- Sorry. This platform isn't really suited for back and forth conversation. I wish it were, then I could say something more helpful than "caveat lector".

Comment: @FutureSecurity Can you please remove the above post immediately.

Comment: @PaulUszak While it may have been written in a rather abrasive tone and it may have been better to simply point out the Dunning–Kruger effect, it's not a problem to point out that the community often disagrees with you or that the downvote/upvote dynamics often hide the community's opinion on some of your posts. Your answer has many factual inaccuracies and falsehoods, and Future Security was just warning OP.

Comment: @forest There aren't any falsehoods in my answer as you can't point any out.  Are  you confused again as you've copied much of my material?  Condoning hate speech isn't cool even if he has the right to say it.  Stick to cryptography please. What do they say here? "Be nice!"

Comment: @PaulUszak I've copied your material? Huh? Anyway, if you want me to go into detail explaining what is wrong with your answer, please create a room to do so. I don't want to use the comments for an extended discussion. Anyway a rude or harsh comment is _not_ hate speech.

Answer (score 6):

A 160-bit seed is plenty for a cryptographically-secure PRNG. We are not going to be able to count to 2<sup>160</sup> any time soon, so there is no need to worry that this is a "gaping hole". While in theory Linux's random driver may have a larger keyspace, it's not going to make a difference in real life. Fortuna does have advantages over Yarrow, but a larger key size is not what's important. What really matters is resistance to side-channel attacks and adequate entropy collection at boot time.

By default, Yarrow-160 actually uses 3DES in counter mode to generate the random output, which gives it approximately 112 bits of security. Fortuna uses any other block cipher in counter mode, but typically 128-bit AES. The Linux randomness driver uses ChaCha20. It starts out with 320 bits of secret material (a 256-bit key and a 64-bit nonce). Each reseed updates the 256-bit key. So yes, Linux has a larger keyspace. No, this doesn't matter in practice. Yarrow, Fortuna, and Linux's CRNG are all secure.

Comment: Thank you very much. If I understand you though, does that mean on macOS it’s technically not possible to generate a trusty cryptographically secure key greater than 160bits? I.e 256bit aes keys generated on macOS are weaker than on other systems despite being “256” bits physically?

Comment: @Woodstock More like 112 bits, if my understanding of its Yarrow-160 implementation is correct.

Comment: so all keys generated on macOS only have a bit strength of 112bits?!

Comment: Regarding whether or not it's possible to generate 256-bit keys with Yarrow-160, if the internal state of the generator is >= 256-bits, then you can make multiple calls to the generator, and combine them for a theoretically secure 256-bit key.

Comment: @forest JFYI Apple released new docs, stating they moved to Fortuna: https://support.apple.com/en-ie/guide/security/seca0c73a75b/web